# Unable to select an item from a hidden RadComboBox

Tags: selenium

It would be very much helpful if I could get a solution for the below problem.

I'm unable to select an item from a hidden `Radcombobox`. The below code just enabled the field and I could see the combobox drops down in a fraction of second but the item specified is not selected. Please assist me correcting my code.

**HTML Script**

```
<a id="cmb_40_Arrow" style="overflow: hidden;display: block;position: relative;outline: none;">select</a>
```

**Java Code**

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", getElement("InterPoint"));                             //This is the combobox field        
new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)        
.withTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)      
.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)        
.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)        
.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {        
@NotNull        
@Override         
public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {        
WebElement element = getElement("CustomerPole");       /*This is the item from the field "Interpoint"*/        
return element != null && element.isDisplayed();        
  }        
});
```

**Tried the below code and it doesn't work either**

```
//waitpgm.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(" //*[@id='pnlHeaderInterconnectionPointInformation']"))).click();    
//waitpgm.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='cmb_40_DropDown']/div/ul/li[2]"))).click();    
//waitpgm.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(getElement("CustomerPole"))).click();
```

Comment: Any updates from anybody on this?